# Should I install a vapor barrier before adding drywall to my garage?

Tags: drywall, garage, vapor-barrier

I'm refinishing my attached garage, and part of the job will be to install drywall. Currently, the walls have faced installation installed are are covered with pegboard. I'll be removing the pegboard and replacing it with drywall. I'm in Ohio so will have to deal with a wide range of weather. The garage space will be heated and air conditioned when all is said and done (mini split).

Should I install a plastic vapor barrier between the studs and the new drywall? I have gotten mixed advice from my research so far. Some things I've read suggest that the plastic is necessary to prevent condensation from rotting out the drywall. Others seem to suggest that adding the plastic could actually *cause* a moisture issue by trapping condensation inside the wall cavity.

What's the best practice in this case? What are the considerations that inform whether or not I should use a vapor barrier?

Edit: I've attached a picture of the wall in question. I removed one of the pegboard panels to get a good look at the insulation. This will give a bit better idea of what I'm working with.
[image: picture of wall showing insulation]

Comment: The paper shown is a vapor barrier.  You should bend the flaps over and staple them to the studs.  And fill in some of the voids.  No need for a second vapor barrier.

Comment: BTW, what's on the outside of your wall?  Siding?  Brick?  Something else?

Comment: The outside of the wall has plywood cladding with vinyl siding.

Comment: Any housewrap ?  Another insulating board?

Comment: Just went out and checked - there's felt paper between the plywood and siding.